# Add Custom action as part of the Action dropdown (AEF)

Tags: acumatica

I would know how to add an Action button but did not manage to identify how to add this under the Actions menu. It is being added as a separate link button and not as part of the actions sub-menu. How can you achieve this please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This post should help with your answer: [Adding Custom Action to "Actions" Drop Down in Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42398301/adding-custom-action-to-actions-drop-down-in-extension)

You can add it by using `AddMenuAction` on your parent button (`action` in this example):

```
MyGraph.action.AddMenuAction(myCustomAction);
```

Comment: Alternative method is to add action by creating Automation Step